# Scraping tabulated data from ballotpedia.org with rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to scrape tabulated data on previous US statewide election results, and I think ballotpedia.org is a good place to be getting this data from - as URLs are in a consistent format for all states.

Here's the code I set up to test it:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)

# STEP 1 - URL COMPONENTS TO SCRAPE FROM
senate_base_url <- "https://ballotpedia.org/United_States_Senate_elections_in_"
senate_state_urls <- gsub(" ", "_", state.name) 
senate_year_urls <- c(",_2012", ",_2014", ",_2016")

# TEST
test_url <- paste0(senate_base_url, senate_state_urls[10], senate_year_urls[2])
```

this results in the following URL: https://ballotpedia.org/United_States_Senate_elections_in_Georgia,_2014

Using the 'selectorgadget' chrome plugin, I selected the table in question containing the election result, and tried parsing it into R as follows:

```
test_data <- read_html(test_url)
test_data <- test_data %>% 
  html_node(xpath = '//*[@id="collapsibleTable0"]') %>% 
  html_table()
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("html_table") : 
  no applicable method for 'html_table' applied to an object of class "xml_missing"
```

Furthermore, the R object `test_data` yields a list with 2 empty elements.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Is the `html_table()` function the wrong one? Using `html_text()` simply returns an `NA` character vector. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks very much :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your xpath statement is incorrect, thus the html_node function is returning a null value.

Here is a solution using the html tags.  "Look for a table tag within a center tag"

```
library(rvest) 

test_data <- read_html(test_url)
test_data <- test_data %>% html_nodes("center table") %>% html_table()
```

Or to retrieve the fully collapsed table use the html tag with class name:

```
collapsedtable<-test_data %>% html_nodes("table.collapsible") %>% 
        html_table(fill=TRUE)
```

Comment: thanks, this worked. so - how did you find the right html-node, i.e. "center table" instead of '//*[@id="collapsibleTable0"]'?

Comment: I use the developer tools in the browser and examine the source code.  It is slower than the selector gadget, but I have more success in understanding the structure.

Answer (score 1):

this works for me:

```
library(httr)
library(XML)

r <- httr::GET("https://ballotpedia.org/United_States_Senate_elections_in_Georgia,_2014")
XML::readHTMLTable(rawToChar(r$content))[[2]]
```